# Way to analyze wifi signals and can store them in an excel format, on python?

Tags: python, macos, wifi

I am currently in need of a way to find wifi networks, analyze their signal strengths and store them in an excel format for my research. I have to do this because I need a more efficient way to gather this information other than using my mac's wireless diagnostics and manually typing all of it into excel myself. Normally I do not mind trying to do that but I have to gather a TON of data to do my research and I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way.

[image: table]

My current research now is figuring out the location of a person by analyzing wifi networks and their signal strengths.

I'd like a method that is linked to python and OSX. I know about the package python-wifi but I keep on getting the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sbin/iwlist'.
```

Apparently this is because it needs to be done on linux and not on Mac.

I'm sorry if this is a vague question or anything, this is my first question on stack overflow so there. Please ask if there is any need of clarification!